# How to compute the class defined by intersection with a square?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, intersection-theory, enumerative-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\Gr{Gr}$Let $\Gr(k,n+k)$ (of course, one can do also for $\Gr(k,\infty)$) be the complex Grassmannian of $k$-planes in $n+k$-dimensional linear space.
It is well-known that Schubert cells can be defined by the dimensions of the intersection with a given flag.
A reasonable question is to ask what is the fundamental class defined by the dimensions of the intersection with other forms.

For example, let us take a square $\begin{array}{rcl}{}_{\nearrow}\!\!\!\!&U+V&\!\!\!\!{}_\nwarrow\\U&&V.\\{}^{\nwarrow}\!\!\!\!&U\cap V&\!\!\!\!{}^{\nearrow}\end{array}$ I want to compute the fundamental class of the closure of
$$\left\{X\in \Gr(k,n+k):\begin{array}{rl}
\dim(X\cap (U+V))&=x+y+z+w\\
\dim(X\cap U)&=x+y\\
\dim(X\cap V)&=x+z\\
\dim(X\cap U\cap V)&=x
\end{array}\right\}$$
where $x$, $y$, $z$, $w$ are given integers. I believe it should be studied or solved in some systematic way.

Here are some remarks.

1. I do not even know how to compute the dimension of it, or whether it is connected, equal dimension.
2. I suspect that the degeneracy loci created by Fulton can be used to compute it.
3. Firstly, we can not take a common basis for three subspaces.
   For example, the diagonal in $\mathbb{C}^2$ with $U=(\mathbb{C},0)$ and $V=(0,\mathbb{C})$.
4. Consider the simplest case $\Gr(1,2)=\mathbb{C}P^1$ with $U=(\mathbb{C},0)$ and $V=(0,\mathbb{C})$.
   $$\left\{X\in \mathbb{C}P^1:\begin{array}{rl}
   \dim(X)&=1\\
   \dim(X\cap U)&=0\\
   \dim(X\cap V)&=0
   \end{array}\right\}=\mathbb{C}P^1\setminus \{0,\infty\}. $$
   So its closure is the complete $\mathbb{C}P^1$. It looks the answer is not that interesting for $k=1$.
5. Whether the closure is to exchange $=$ to $\geq$?
6. In general, for three subspaces, (let me call them $V_1$, $V_2$, $V_3$ temporarily). There need not be a basis $B$ such that $B\cap V_i$ forms a basis for each $V_i$ simultaneously. From linear algebra (well, quiver representations) we know we can write $\mathbb{C}^n=A\oplus B$ such that each $V_i=V_i\cap A\oplus V_i\cap B$ and each $V_i\cap B$ admits a common basis, and $(A\cap V_i)_{i=1,2,3}$ is isomorphic to $(U\oplus 0,0\oplus U, \operatorname{diag}\Delta_U)$ for some $U$.